# How to match either `[` or `]` (brackets) with regular expression?

Tags: regular-expression

I am aware that pattern `[abc]` matches a single character that is either `a` or `b` or `c` in the regular expressions, but how can I match for either `[` or `]`? I don't know how to escape them properly.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to use is `[][]`. Take GNU `grep` as an example. All of the following three will do.

```
grep '[][]' file
grep -P '[][]' file
grep -E '[][]' file
```

**Explanation**: The bracket expression in regular expression cannot have an empty body (Try `grep '[]' file` and an error will be reported), so the first `[` actually goes with the last `]`. The `[` inside the pair of brackets does not interfere because bracket expression cannot be nested, so once a `[` is seen, the RE engine will look for the first `]` starting from the 2nd character after it as the closing `]`. Inside a bracket expression, only `[:class:]` `[.coll.]` `[=equiv=]` and `c-c` ranges, together with the `^` that appears at the beginning are treated specially, other characters are treated literally with no need for escaping (see comment by @dave_thompson_085 for link to manual pages).

Comment: [As stated in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) "... if you want to make the ‘]’ character a list item, you must put it first". But `[:class:] [.coll.] [=equiv=]` and `c-c` ranges and initial `^` are NOT literal in a bracket expression. All the cases with `[` are handled by putting it at the end, `-` is handled by putting it at the end _or_ the beginning (modulo `^` if used), and `^` by putting it _not_ at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I will update the answer.

Comment: That's different in perl/PCRE regexps (and the EREs of many awk implementations, also GNU `sed` without POSIXLY_CORRECT, `vim` with `nocompatible`...), where one can  use `[\[\]]` (i.e. backslash is also special inside bracket expressions). Or IOW, if you also want backslash to be included in that list portable, you'd need `[][\\]` (double the backslash).

Comment: Can you expand it to an answer? I will accept it.